# Testcafe Running Multiple Fixtures or Tests consecutively from within the same "file"

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've been working with Testcafe and have had some issues working with multiple "Fixtures" or "Tests" from within the same "file".

IE TESTFILE.js:

```
import { Selector, Role } from 'testcafe';
import Games from '../Pages/Games.js'
import {partnerAdmin} from '../Data/Roles.js'
const config = require('../Data/config.json')

fixture `Test Fixture #1`
.page `${config.envs.dev.baseUrl}`

test('Testing Test #1', async t => {
  await t 
    .useRole(partnerAdmin)

  await t
    .expect(Selector(Games.gamesList).exists).ok()
    .expect(Selector(Games.topRowGame).exists).ok()
    .click(Games.gameActionsBtn)
   
});

fixture `Test Fixture #2`
.page `${config.envs.dev.baseUrl}`

test('Testing Test #2', async t => {
  await t 
    .useRole(partnerAdmin)

  await t
    // DO OTHER STUFF
   
});
```

When I try this the 1st fixture will run perfectly... HOWEVER, the 2nd Fixture will stop at the login page. It's as if the 'useRole' function is failing the second time it's getting called.

I'm using the Roles as followed in the documentation.

IE Roles.js:

```
import { Selector, Role, t } from 'testcafe';
import Login from '../Pages/Login.js'
const config = require('../Data/config.json')

const partnerAdmin = Role(`${config.envs.dev.baseUrl}`, async t => {
  await 
  Login.login(config.users.partnerAutoAdmin.name, config.users.partnerAutoAdmin.pass)
});

export { partnerAdmin }
```

It doesn't matter the order I place the "Fixtures" or "Tests" in. I can literally swap the 2nd fixture to before the 1st and it still does the same thing.  The first runs, but the second just straight up fails as if it can't remember what it just did when it hits the login page the second time.

Anyone have any idea what I might be missing here? I'm using Roles and page models that seem to be working normally. Unfortunately the first test runs, but fails to continue on through the second for some reason even if I did just duplicate the same login/roles setup.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. It might be related to how the app you're testing works.

Comment: I've been observing the behavior and making adjustments. It appears that there's an issue in how the behavior of "Fixtures" and/or "Tests" triggers an automatic "reset" of execution which forces a "Logout like" behavior. 

Perhaps I'm using the tool wrong, but I have multiple "components" on a single page I'd like to test. For organizational cleanliness I'm trying to isolate out the "actions" that interact with different components into different "test" blocks. 

Unfortunately it appears that testcafe is hard killing the "execution" once it finishes a "test" block.

Comment: I "believe" ... I figured it out. It appears that it's due to how the Role Page Caching works. 

If I disable the page caching on the "fixture" or "test" level it works and runs successfully. I had to add `.disablePageCaching` on the "fixture" to get it to work properly without logging the session out prior to the 2nd test running.

Also had to add the `{preserverUrl: true}` property  on the 'Role'.